# How to set pulseaudio's pauvcontrol default to "FFT based equalizer..."

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using pulseaudio-equalizer to equalise the output of VLC, but it only works if I 

a) start qpaeq then

b) start pavucontrol and change "Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo" to "FFT based equalizer on ..."

Is there any way to set the default to "FFT based equalizer" so that I would only need to start both programs for the effect to occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In order to start the EQ and make it the default output automatically at startup you have to add some commands to PulseAudio's default.pa file, either in its main/system location

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

... or in a user-specific copy of it (good thing to have separately in case you ever need to return to the old form of the file after too many modifications - you'd just delete/rename the user one and the system one would take priority again)

```
~/.config/pulse/default.pa
```

So at the bottom of the file you add something like this:

```
### Load the integrated pulseaudio equalizer and dbus modules
load-module module-equalizer-sink sink_name=MyFancyNewEQSink
load-module module-dbus-protocol
set-default-sink MyFancyNewEQSink
```

... and then restart Ubuntu. (You could restart just PulseAudio but you might lose the functionality of the dedicated volume keys on your keyboard. I'd just restart the OS itself to set everything right.)

Note that this makes QPAEQ the default output for everything, not just VLC.