# pulseaudio-equalizer is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, equalizer

I ran

```
:~$ apt install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

An important detail, no icon was included in the Gnome Applications menu. I think it is important to fix it. So, I ran

```
:~$ qpaeq
```

and I received the error messages

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use  QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
There was an error connecting to pulseaudio, please make sure you have the pulseaudio dbus module loaded, exiting…
```

I ran

```
:~$ pulseaudio
```

and I received the message

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.  
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

So, I loaded the modules that were missing

```
:~$ pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink  
:~$ pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

and the equalizer opened and it didn't work (the sound wasn't changing).

Another important detail, why do theses modules are not loaded by default? I think this is another thing to be fixed.

I created the file `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` with the lines

```
load-module module-equalizer-sink  
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

and I restarted to check. After the Gnome login the computer start to "freeze" by some seconds. In this condition, if I run

```
:~$ pactl list modules short | grep module-dbus-protocol
```

the terminal stops until I do `Crtl+C`.

If I try to load some module (`module-equalizer-sink` or `module-dbus-protocol`) I received an error message. So strange...

I restarted the computer again and the "freezing" happened again. So, in this way I deleted the file `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` to come back to the early situation. I restarted and the "freezing" didn't happened again.

I tried another solution. I installed

```
:~$ apt install pulseeffects
```

and the equalizer was not working. Looking the pulseeffects FAQ,

https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/FAQ

I found a solution, to run

```
:~$ apt install lsp-plugins
```

Delete the folder `~/.config/gstreamer-1.0` (if it exists)

After to close the `pulseeffects` (if is opened) and run

```
:~$ dconf reset -f /com/github/wwmm/pulseeffects/
```

In this way, the equalizer of the pulseeffects worked.

Comment: One thing you should know: if `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` exist, pulseaudio will not read from `/etx/pulse/default.pa`, so if you create user configuration in `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`, you should copy content from `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` first and then edit it. Please take a look at `man default.pa`.

Comment: Thank you @mook765. I didn't pay attention to this important detail. I will try after if works. :)

Comment: Do I read this correctly your question has the answer at the bottom of the question?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the comment of @mook765 above, I included the lines

```
### Modules for the Equalizer
load-module module-equalizer-sink
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

in the end of the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. I checked the modules were not present and commented in the file originally.

I rebooted and I observed Gnome didn't "freeze" more after the login.

I ran `qpaeq` and the equalizer opened normally. I played an audio in the VLC and after in the Audacity to do some tests and the equalizer was not working.

I opened the Gnome Settings and I found a new device in `Gnome Settings > Sound > Output > Output Device` called `FFT based equalizer on Built-in Audio Analog Stereo`. When I selected this option the sound mute, so that, it didn't work. I pressed the `Test` button and there was no sound.

So, the `pulseaudio-equalizer` continue not working.

Highlighting, at last I guess there are two important points to be fixed in the Ubuntu 20.04 for `pulseaudio-equalizer`:

1. Include the `qpaeq` icon/shortcut in the Gnome Applications after the `pulseaudio-equalizer` installation.
2. Load the modules `module-equalizer-sink` and `module-dbus-protocol` and include than in the `/etc/pulse/default.pa` file after the `pulseaudio-equalizer` installation.

Beyond this, there is a third important point to be fixed: what is missing to the `pulseaudio-equalizer` to work? :)

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/910010/590937), this worked for me. I just installed `pulseaudio-equalizer` in 20.04 and faced the same problems. I remember that I once wrote an answer about this topic and tried the mentioned solution, it worked.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I installed `pulseaudio-equalizer` from the official repository now, no need to add PPA as described in the linked answer.

Comment: I found that the answer that @mook765 linked above fixes the problem for me. The key point is installing `pavucontrol` and configuring the program you're equalizing to use "FFT based equalizer on [device]". I set up pulseaudio-equalizer to run through pulseeffects, as I found that the equalizer still didn't actually change the audio in pulseeffects, but that may not be an issue for you. I also recommend checking [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980709/how-to-set-pulseaudios-pauvcontrol-default-to-fft-based-equalizer) to set up the pavucontrol to be automatic, so it doesn't reset.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem symptom**: I faced a similar problem - after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04.5 to 20.04.1, `pulseaudio-equalizer` could not be enabled:

```bash
$ pulseaudio-equalizer enable
```

```
PulseAudio Equalizer/LADSPA Processor 4.0 (29.01.2017)

... (10 lines omitted)

Equalizer status: [disabled]
Equalizer configuration status: [enabled]
Equalizer plugin: [mbeq_1197/mbeq]

... (3 lines omitted)
```

(That is, I tried to enable `pulseaudio-equalizer` but it remained disabled)

---

**Problem crux**: When I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04.5 to 20.04.1, `/usr/lib/ladspa/lsp-plugins-ladspa.so` seem to have disappeared.

I realized this after seeing [this thread about the equalizer in pulseeffects being greyed-out](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244157), where it turns out the OP was missing LSP.

---

**Solution**: Similar to the workaround where you installed `lsp-plugins`, I went to the [LSP website](https://lsp-plug.in/?page=download), downloaded the latest `lsp-plugins-ladspa`, extracted `lsp-plugins-ladspa.so` and placed it in `/usr/lib/ladspa/`.

Afterwards, `$ pulseaudio-equalizer enable` works as expected, and I don't need `pulseeffects`.